# How to link custom "Sent" Page via PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

I've recently started working with PHPMailer to email my contactforms and after some puzzling, it works great. The only 'downside' is that the user gets redirected after sending an email. For example:

If one would fill in the form [here](http://chaudiere.mcore.one/contact), they will be redirected to another page like [this one](http://chaudiere.mcore.one/php/contact.php) when the message sent succesfully.

My HTML for my form is the following:

```
<form class="form ajax-contact-form" method="post" action="php/contact.php">
    <div class="alert alert-success hidden" id="contact-success">
      &nbsp; <strong>Votre message a &eacute;t&eacute; envoy&eacute; avec
      succ&egrave;s!</strong> Merci, nous contacterons vous d&egrave;s que possible.
    </div>

    <div class="alert alert-danger hidden" id="contact-error">
      &nbsp; <strong>Votre message n'a pas &eacute;t&eacute; envoy&eacute;.</strong> Vous
      avez tout rempli correctement?
    </div>

    <div class="row col-p10">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="mb10"><input type="text" name="name_" id="name_" required="" class=
        "form-control" placeholder="Votre nom" /></label>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="mb10"><input type="text" name="adress_" id="subject_" required=""
        class="form-control" placeholder="Votre adresse" /></label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row col-p10">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="mb10"><input type="number" name="zipcode_" id="zipcode_" required=
        "" class="form-control" placeholder="Code postal" /></label>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="mb10"><input type="text" name="city_" id="city_" required="" class=
        "form-control" placeholder="Ville ou commune" /></label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row col-p10">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="mb10"><input type="tel" name="phone_" id="phone_" required=""
        class="form-control" placeholder=
        "Votre num&eacute;ro de t&eacute;l&eacute;phone" /></label>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <label class="mb10"><input type="email" name="email_" id="email_" required=""
        class="form-control" placeholder="Votre adresse d'email" /></label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label><select name="select_" id="select_" required="" class="form-control">
          <option value="Invalid">
            Choisi un option
          </option>

          <option value="CV Ketel huren">
            Je veux louer une chaudi&egrave;re
          </option>

          <option value="CV Ketel kopen">
            Je veux acheter une chaudi&egrave;re
          </option>

          <option value="Ik wens meer informatie">
            Je veux plus d'infos
          </option>
        </select></label>
      </div>
    </div><label>
    <textarea name="message_" id="message_" cols="30" rows="10" class="form-control"
    placeholder="Votre message (optionel)">
</textarea></label>

    <div class="mb40"></div>

    <div class="clearfix">
      <div class="pull-left">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-icon btn-e">Envoi</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

The php for my form is the following:

```
<?php

session_cache_limiter('nocache');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', 0));
header('Content-type: application/json');

// Include PHPMailer class
include("./PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

// grab reCaptcha library
require_once "./reCaptcha/recaptchalib.php";

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Enter your email address below.
$to_address = "info@cvketelshuren.com"; 

// Enter your secret key (google captcha)
$secret = "Leftout for apparent reasons";

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// Verify if data has been entered
if(!empty($_POST['name_']) || !empty($_POST['adress_']) || !empty($_POST['zipcode_']) || !empty($_POST['city_']) || !empty($_POST['phone_']) || !empty($_POST['email_']) || !empty($_POST['select_'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name_'];
    $adress = $_POST['adress_'];
    $zipcode = $_POST['zipcode_'];
    $city = $_POST['city_'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone_'];
    $email = $_POST['email_'];
    $select = $_POST['select_'];

    // Configure the fields list that you want to receive on the email.
    $fields = array(
        0 => array(
            'text' => 'Naam',
            'val' => $_POST['name_']
        ),
        1 => array(
            'text' => 'Adres',
            'val' => $_POST['adress_']
        ),
        2 => array(
            'text' => 'Stad',
            'val' => $_POST['zipcode_']." ".$_POST['city_']
        ),
        3 => array(
            'text' => 'Select',
            'val' => $_POST['select_']
        ),
        4 => array(
            'text' => 'Telefoonnummer',
            'val' => $_POST['phone_']
        ),
        5 => array(
            'text' => 'Mailadres',
            'val' => $_POST['email_']
        ),
        6 => array(
            'text' => 'Bericht',
            'val' => $_POST['message_']
        )
    );


    $message = "Waarde collega,<br>Er werd een contactformulier ingevuld op de site cvketelshuren.com<br>Gelieve hieronder de gegevens van de klant terug te vinden.<br>";
    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $message .= $field['text'].": " . htmlspecialchars($field['val'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
    }


    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->IsSMTP(); // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0; // Debug Mode


    // If you don't receive the email, try to configure the parameters below:

    $mail =  new PHPMailer;
        $mail->Host = 'mailout.one.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = '***************';
        $mail->Password = '************';
        $mail->SMTPSecure = false;
        $mail->Port = 25;


    $mail->From = $email;
    $mail->FromName = $name;
    $mail->AddAddress($to_address); 
    $mail->AddReplyTo($email, $name);


    if (!empty($_POST['send_copy_'])) {
        $mail->AddAddress($email);
    }


    $mail->IsHTML(true); // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

    $mail->Subject = 'Vraag via CV Ketels Huren [NL]';
    $mail->Body    = $message;


    // Google CAPTCHA
    $resp = null; // empty response
    $reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret); // check secret key

    // if submitted check response
    if ($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) {
        $resp = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse(
            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
            $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
        );
    }

    // if captcha is ok, send email
    if ($resp != null && $resp->success) {

        if($mail->Send()) {
            $result = array ('response'=>'success');
        } else {
            $result = array ('response'=>'error' , 'error_message'=> $mail->ErrorInfo);
        }

    } else {
        $result = array ('response'=>'error' , 'error_message'=>'Google ReCaptcha did not work');
    }

    echo json_encode($result);

} else {

    $result = array ('response'=>'error' , 'error_message'=>'Data has not been entered');
    echo json_encode($result);

}
?>
```

As you can see, an error and success message was already coded in but if redirecting is something that should happen, I want to code a custom HTML-page. Anybody that can help me set the redirect so I can start coding?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You are not doing any redirects here. Your form tag contains `action="php/contact.php"`, so that's where the form will submit to. If you want to go somewhere else after processing the form submission and sending a message, you can do a redirect like this:

```
header('Location: some_other_url/page.php');
```

If the form contains errors, you could redirect back to the form, passing error messages in the URL parameters.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I'm unsure where I can input this header? This is currently my code for sending the email: https://jsfiddle.net/Lp3gyuh1/ (PHP in HTML textfield).

Comment: That code looks like it's expecting to be called from an XHR, not a human form submission, which doesn't correlate with your other code. You should include relevant code in your question, not on external sites.

Comment: Just updated the fiddle to include the full code of contact.php, please check here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lp3gyuh1/1/
Created a fiddle because it was quite impossible to link you to the source code on my test server